# how to Know file served for download is completely downloaded?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

Anonymous user clicks the link on email for download ..

which redirect him on my view..

```
def fileview(request):
    linktoken = request.GET.get('token')
    b = cache.get(linktoken)
    if b:
        the_file = 'gardentruck.zip'
        filename = os.path.basename(the_file)
        response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(open(the_file)), content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(the_file)[0])
        response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(the_file)    
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
        cache.delete(linktoken)     
        return  response
    else:
        return HttpResponse("token is expired")
```

1.just want  to know is there any way to Know the download request made by email click is complete or not ..

so that i could make the link  it expire

2.ideal time period to expiry of link

Comment: You can try to use `request-finished` signal,  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#request-finished